# How to round up in gurobi python?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

I am working on a math model using `Python`.

I have 4 datasets:

```
1. Trucks=[1:263]
2. Slots=[0:23]
3. Companies=[0:3]
4. Blocks=[0:7]
```

2 binary decision variables `X` and `Y` and 1 binary dependent decision variable `Z (Z=X+Y)`.

I want to add the continuous-time parameters `(tp+twg)` to the index `s` (which is an integer) to make the truck access the terminal in the time slot after `(tp+twg)`.

So I have to round the value of `(s+tp+twg)` to the next time slot.
I used the function below `math.ceil()` but I got an error in time slot 23. Gurobi can't calculate the value of (0,0,1,24) because the upper limit of the set `S` is 23. `S` refers to the time slot at which the truck will access to the terminal in `X` and `Y`. In `Z`, it refers to the time slot at which the truck will arrive at the terminal gate.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
    for i in Trucks:
        for k in Companies:
            for b in Blocks:
                for s in Slots:
                    if 0 <= s < 23:
                        cont_9=m.addConstr(X[i,k,b, math.ceil(s+tp[s]+twg[s])]+Y[i,k,b, math.ceil(s+tp[s]+twg[s])] <= Z[i,k,b,s])
```

Comment: What is the error? What are the variables? We need a minimal reproducible example to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I clarified the error exactly above.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the function `y=ceil(x)` can be implemented as:

```
  y >= x
  y <= x + 0.999
  y integer
```

However, note that you cannot use a variable to index decision variables. That will require some reformulations. Remember that a linear model only allows, well linear things.